# Docker on EC2: disk performance limited by the disk docker itself is installed

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, performance, amazon-ec2, io

When running a docker container on EC2 with instance store we noticed that, despite mounting a volume on the instance store, the container could not use the local disk full capacity. We could even reproduce the behavior using the [fio](https://github.com/axboe/fio) benchmark application. Bellow more details:

- Instance Type: AWS m6idn.large
- SO: Amazon Linux 2
- According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/general-purpose-instances.html on the m6idn.large instance type we can get up to 33.5k iops on the instance store disk.

When running a benchmark program to simulate our application workload we got the following results:

- outside docker container: throughput: +/- 136MiB/s, iops=34009.

```
sudo fio --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1     --name=seq-read --filename=seq-read --bs=4k --iodepth=256 --size=100m     --readwrite=read --runtime=120 --time_based --numjobs=4 --group_reporting
```

- inside docker container: throughput: +/- 11.8MiB/s, iops=3023.

```
docker run --rm -v `pwd`/data:/iops/data tooldockers/iops     --randrepeat=1 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --gtod_reduce=1     --name=seq-read --filename=seq-read --bs=4k --iodepth=256 --size=100m     --readwrite=read --runtime=120 --time_based --numjobs=4 --group_reporting
```

We ran all commands on the instance store disk and mounted the volume on the instance store disk also.

As we can see, when running without docker we maxed the IOPS from the instance. From a docker container we got nearly 10 times less iops and throughput. After more testing we could check that, if we give the instance a root disk (that is an EBS) with, let's say, 4k IOPS, the benchmark would top at 4k IOPS.

It think it's weird to be limited by the disk Docker itself is installed as we're not using it directly, as the contaner's volume is directly mounted on the instance store disk.

Is there any configuration or change we can do to fully utilize the instance store disk capacity when running from inside a docker container?